# Legal Ramifications For Student Paid Paper

Tags: paper-submission, legal-issues

What legal ramifications can I turn to after determining someone has paid another student to write their paper?

Comment: Are you another student or faculty?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton student, but I figured this question could be general.

Comment: Unclear. It depends on your role and your relation to "someone" and to "another student". If you are mining charcoal tens of thousands of kilometers away, then probably none.

Comment: Is this a paper for a class or a peer-reviewed paper for publication?

Comment: @aeismail just a class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking whether paying someone to write your homework is illegal?

Answer (score 1):

Tell your instructor what you've observed or know about the incident and leave it up to them to deal with the problem.  If you're telling the truth, you have no legal exposure.

Comment: I have discussed this with the adjunct instructor at the community college and they seem reluctant to do anything.

Comment: Is it possible that the adjunct instructor is « associated » with the student’s supervisor? And as such does not want to go there...

Comment: Do you have sufficient evidence to send to the editor of the paper...

Comment: Telling someone something usually does not have legal remifications.

Comment: @SolarMike that is completely possible.

Comment: @SolarMike it isn't a journal just an assignment but just for a class.